# ClassCastException on a subclass of ListFragment using compatibility library

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-1.6-donut, android-support-library

**This only happens when using the compatibility library for pre-3.0 devices**

I'm getting an error that I cannot pin down. I have an Activity with a ListFragment and standard Fragment. It is just like the example provided in the Developers section of the Android Dev Guide.

**ListFragment Subclass (no functions overridden)**

```
public class ItemListFragment extends ListFragment
```

**MainActivity**

```
public class ItemViewerActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.item_viewer);
    }
}
```

**Xml Layout for MainActivity**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:orientation="horizontal">
  <fragment class="org.example.ItemListFragment"
    android:id="@+id/item_list_fragment"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
  <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/item_info_frame"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**Error Message from LogCat**

ERROR/AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.example.ItemListFragment cannot be cast to android.app.Fragment

Answer (score 35, accepted):

After some serious googling, I found an article that pointed out a nice little tidbit. When using the compatibility library, your activities that use fragments have to extend FragmentActivity. Once I did that, the error did not present itself again.

Comment: I also got this error when I was correctly using `FragmentActivity` but forgot to use `getSupportFragmentManager()` instead of `getFragmentManager()`.

Comment: Also if the `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);` is missing on the Activity the same error will rise and not the usual `SuperNotCalledException`

Comment: I was wondering how would I extend ActionBarActivity and FragmentActivity both at the same time, but then I found that extending ActionBar activity takes care of it!

Answer (score 1):

For me the problem was that I had forgotten to change the manifest. Following the suggestion of the tutorial I converted my Activity to a Fragment and made a shell Activity to call it. My manifest still pointed to the Fragment class leading to a Class Cast Exception.